# How to convert year format YY into YYYY in PHP

Tags: php, date

I need to convert year(YY) to YYYY. Here i am try to use `date` function in PHP but not getting the expected result.

```
$expiry_year = "30"; //year=2030
echo date('Y',strtotime($expiry_year)); //Result: 1970
echo date('Y',$expiry_year); //Result: 1970
```

Expected Result: 2030

Thanks To All!

Comment: Coding languages are very bad at _Making guesses_ If you know it should be  2030 concatenate a 20 on the front

Comment: Your year "30" will always return 1970. This is due to the Unixtime only starting on the 1st January 1970

Comment: Make this string like 01-01-30 then use

Comment: How about `30+2000` since you don't provide any other requirements? If it needs more complicated handling, add some more logic.

Comment: @Sunil Pachlangia Thanks! your logic is correct and I am getting the result.

Comment: @RamaLingam Hope my Employer know this as well (Just joking).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, use createFromFormat

```
$date = "30";
$dates = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', $date);
//now to get the outpu:
$arr = $dates->format('Y'); // output : 2030
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/701195)**

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Note:
>   If the number of the year is specified in a two digit format, the values between 00-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999. See the notes below for possible differences on 32bit systems (possible dates might end on 2038-01-19 03:14:07).

For this you can use [`date_create_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) Alias of the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method like as

```
$expiry_year = "30";
$date = date_create_from_format('y',$expiry_year);
echo $date->format('Y'); //2030
```

[**Docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes)

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', '30');
echo $date->format('Y');
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
$expiry_year = "30";
$ce = substr(date('Y'),0,2); // Check the century
$ny = substr(date('Y'),2,2); // Check current year (2 digits)
if($expiry_year < $ny) {
    $next_ce = $ce+1;
    $output = $next_ce.$expiry_year;
} else {
    $output = $ce.$expiry_year;
}
```

Something like that ? :D

Comment: This is not my expect solution. Thnaks

Comment: This should help poeple with php lower than 5.2 :)

Comment: Your code return Result: 2130

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer with "<" instead of ">"... My bad.

Comment: Assume `$expiry_year = "08";` then return `2108` Totally wrong

Comment: Yeah right... The answer is not correct in your mind knowing what you wanted... But the logic was there and you could just modify a bit the code and it's working... Like I said, It'll help someone with PHP lower than 5.2 !

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer.